# Running distributed jobs using bash

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have access to a few machines to run on (machine0, machine, etc.).  They all have the access to an executable and a series of input files, is there a way to use bash to run the jobs through ssh so that I don't have to ssh in to every machine and run each one individually?
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is made to solve this problem.

Comment: Hey @Tichodroma, yeah I use that for running many different processes locally at the moment e.g. running ./Myexec input1, ./Myexec input2, etc.
All at once but can GNU parallel work over a network?

Comment: Yes. Just read the first sentence: "GNU parallel is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one **or more** computers."

Comment: This was regarding using back in particular

Answer (score 1):

[Set up passwordless authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) on your host machine and then let your bash script call your binaries/scripts [through ssh](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) (`ssh user@remote <command>`).

Comment: I have passwordless access setup but I didnt know you could call jobs through ssh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of jobs to run and manage, you might want to install a job scheduler such as [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/) or [Condor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) so that you do not need to wory where and when to get your jobs running.